# Upload image using AFnetworking did not response anything

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, afnetworking, image-uploading

Here's the problem :

1. I want to upload image immediately after finish choosing image from imagepicker.
2. So, I put my code to upload image using afnetworking in imagepicker delegate method.
3. But it doesn't response anything.

   ```
   //set the imageview to current image after choosing
   profilePic.image = image;

   //dismiss the imagepicker
   [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

   //start upload image code
   NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"steventi1901", @"username",
                           UIImagePNGRepresentation(profilePic.image), @"profile_pic",
                           nil];

    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:updateProfile];
   NSData *imageToUpload = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profilePic.image);

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"PUT" path:@"" parameters:params
                                               constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
       [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageToUpload name:@"file" fileName:@"temp.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
       //NSLog(@"dalem");
   }];

   AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

   [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
       NSString *response = [operation responseString];
       NSLog(@"response: [%@]",response);

   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

       if([operation.response statusCode] == 403){
           NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
           return;
       }
       NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);

   }];

   [operation start];
   //end upload image code
   ```

It really didn't response anything so i didn't know if the process fail or success.

Comment: have you tried putting breakpoints to see if its being called?

Answer (score 1):

Best and Easy way to upload Image using Afnetworking.

Please use below AFNetworking.

**pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.4'**

```
//Create manager

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    //parameters if any
    NSMutableDictionary *AddPost = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [AddPost setValue:@"Addparma" forKey:@"param"];

    NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.addyourmainurl.com"];;    

    NSLog(@"AddPost %@",AddPost);

    [manager POST:url parameters:[AddPost copy] constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

        //add image data one by one

        for(int i=0; i<[Array count];i++)
        {
            UIImage *eachImage  = [Array objectAtIndex:i];

            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(eachImage,0.5);

            [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d",i] fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg",i ] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

        }  

    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

have you set the delegate of the picker?

```
[yourPicker setDelegate:self]
```